API Login with Bitwarden command bw login --apikey
I'm working on a Node.js script to log in to a Bitwarden vault using the command bw login --apikey. However, after running this command, a prompt appears asking for the client_id. After providing the client_id, another prompt appears for the client_secret. I'm having trouble passing these values automatically to the prompts. Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this?


const input = `test  test1`;
      // Spawn a child process to handle the interactive login process
      const child = spawnSync('bw', ['login', '--apikey'], {
        input: input,
        stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe']
      });

      if (child.error) {
        throw child.error;
      }

      if (child.stderr && child.stderr.toString()) {
        console.error(`stderr: ${child.stderr.toString()}`);
      }

      if (child.stdout && child.stdout.toString()) {
        console.log(`stdout: ${child.stdout.toString()}`);
      }

      if (child.status !== 0) {
        console.log(`Bitwarden login process exited with code ${child.status}`);
        throw new Error('Failed to log into Bitwarden');
      }
    }



result im getting
as u can see in the picture it adds both values to the first prompt!
